# Remote launcher start music player and play

Tags: android, windows

**what I want to archive:**

I want remote-launcher to execute my media player (ie. Musicbee) and play the last playlist.
Is there a way to archive this in one function.

Or two functions:
1. starting media player
2. playing starts (batch?!)
 - Maybe one could use the same functions used on some keyboard-keys play/pause/next/prev.

Any ideas?!

Greez!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to communicate with your app remotely is to use a push notification (like GCM).

GCM will listen, and lanch a GCMIntent in your local code, where you can do whatever you wish pretty much (so you could launch your media player from here, and start a playlist).

Comment: Actually I'm using http://owtroid.com/remotelauncher/mediawiki/index.php?title=Remote_Launcher

Which, already has a listen server, I just need the variables to do the "play"-stuff ;)

Comment: The docs cover how to do this: in the section - Launching a program

Comment: Maybe I'm not clear enough.
I know how to launch a program, I need to know how to autoplay things.